# How do you use @available for a method that has been renamed?

Tags: ios, swift

PushKit has a new method in iOS 11 that is intended to replace one in iOS 10.

It is not possible to use the iOS 10 method when building using iOS 11 as base SDK (I'm currently using Xcode 9.2B) as there is a compiler error saying the method has been renamed.
But its also not possible to use the iOS 11 method and then run the app on an iOS 10 device as there will be an unrecognized selector exception.

I can't use #available{}else{} as its a entire method.

So I did this

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 11.0)
public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType)
{
 ...   
}
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)
{
    ...
}
```

OR:

```
@available(iOS 11, *)
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void)
{
...

@available(iOS 10, *)
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType)
{
...
```

But both of these results in a compilation error on the second declaration saying its been renamed.

How do I get to use either the iOS 11 or the iOS 10 version?

(The app doesn't support versions < 10)

Comment: Shouldn’t having `completion` in the first but not second function distinguish the two `pushRegistry`s?

Comment: Just use the old version. You don’t need to use the new API under iOS 11.

Comment: @Dopapp, if I remove both of the available's then I still get the error on the 2nd about it having been renamed.

Comment: @rmaddy. The completion handler needs to be called with iOS 11. But anyway, what would I do if I re-build in iOS 12, then IOS13 and so on. If I just use the old, when can I ever use the new one?

Comment: If I recall correctly, when I had a similar issue with AVCapturePhotoDelegate I only had the @available attribute for the new function. Does that resolve it?

Comment: @Dopapp, if I only have the available tag for the iOS11 method, I'm still getting that compilation error on the old method.

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with PushKit. Are these delegate methods of some variable you explicitly set the delegate for (ie `registry.delegate=self`)?

Comment: @Dopapp Yes they are delegates of the PKPushRegistryDelegate protocol which are implemented in the AppDelegate class, which also has a voipRegistry.delegate = self; line

Comment: I just created a little test app and added both versions of the delegate method. I set the project's deployment target to iOS 10 and the Base SDK is set to 11.1 with Xcode 9.1. I get no message about the old delegate being renamed. It works just fine with no use of `@available`.

Comment: @Gruntcakes i don't think so

Comment: @Gruntcakes Could be. I don't have Xcode 9.2 to try it out. Perhaps you should show a minimal, complete class that replicates your issue. Maybe there's something else in your class causing the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy No it wasn't Xcode 9.2. I just tried with 9.1 and its the same.

Comment: @Gruntcakes OK then post a complete minimal class that replicates your error so someone can see if it works or fails for them.

Comment: @rmaddy. I reduced the app delegate down to litteraly nothing other than these and its still present. There must be something in the build settings/configuration causing some issue. I'll have to create a project from scratch and compare for build settings differences.

Comment: @rmaddy. I know the difference- my app is still on Swift 3.2, your test app is Swift 4.0. Switch your test app to 3.2 to see it.

Comment: @Gruntcakes That's it. I just changed my test app to use Swift 3.2 and I get errors. The `for` parameter should be `forType`.

Comment: @rmaddy. Thanks for creating your test app. Wouldn't have got this far and solved it easily without it.

Comment: @Gruntcakes See my new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the issue here is a difference between Swift 3 and Swift 4 as well as the additional parameter to the one delegate method as of iOS 11.

The following code compiles clean with Swift 3.2 using a Deployment Target of iOS 10 and a Base SDK of iOS 11.1:

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, PKPushRegistryDelegate {
    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, forType type: PKPushType) {

    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {
        pushRegistry(registry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith: payload, for: type) {
            // no-op
        }
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Do what is needed

        completion()
    }
}
```

And the following compiles clean with Swift 4:

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, PKPushRegistryDelegate {
    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {

    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
        pushRegistry(registry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith: payload, for: type) {
            // no-op
        }
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Do what is needed

        completion()
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two sets of code is that under Swift 3, the first two methods have a parameter named `forType` while under Swift4 it is named `for`.

The new iOS 11 API uses `for` as that parameter regardless of Swift version.

The remaining question now is do you actually need to supply two copies of the first two delegate methods, one set with `for` and one set with `forType` to ensure all of the delegate methods are actually called under all iOS versions regardless of which Swift version you use?

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll run some tests tomorrow to see what happens during execution time.

Comment: Carefully read (and test) the very last paragraph in my answer. Please provide feedback or update my answer once you have a definitive answer for that last question.

Comment: If both are implemented then only one is called at run time - the OS automatically calls the earlier or later variant depending upon the version of the OS upon which the code is executing

Comment: @Gruntcakes What about the `pushRegistry(_:didUpdate:for[Type]:)` delegate, for example? Do you need the `for` or `forType` version? Or both? Does it depend on iOS version or does it depend on Swift version?

Comment: In my app (Swift 3.2) I have only declared the forType variant of didUpdate and this gets called on both iOS 10 and iOS 11. I haven't had time to access if or when the other may or may not be needed.